# How to go to a new line after a certain line length?

Tags: java, arrays, string, formatting

I have an array that needs to go to a new line after it hits a certain character limit, but I don't want it to cut off the number. I tried converting the array to a string to get rid of the brackets and spaces, but I can't seem to string to go to a new line at the correct spot. How do I accomplish this? Thanks!

Current Code (Its a mess I've tried many different solutions from other posts)

```
System.out.println(n + " (" + numDivisors + " proper divisors)");
    System.out.print("...proper divisors: ");

    String temp = Arrays.toString(properDivisors).replace("]", ",").replace(" ", "");
    String finalDiv = temp.substring(1, temp.length());
    if (finalDiv.length() > len) {
        for (int i = len; i <= len; i--){
            if (finalDiv.charAt(len) == ',') {
                finalDiv = finalDiv.replaceAll(".{" + i + "}", "$0\n\t\t    ");
                System.out.print(finalDiv);
            }
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println(finalDiv);
    }
```

Desired Output

```
86268 (47 proper divisors)                                                               
...proper divisors: 1,2,3,4,6,7,12,13,14,21,26,28,39,42,52,78,79,84,91,
                    156,158,182,237,273,316,364,474,546,553,948,1027,
                    1092,1106,1659,2054,2212,3081,3318,4108,6162,6636,
                    7189,12324,14378,21567,28756,43134,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be easier if you build a string, and only print it when you exceed the line length. Don't munge `Arrays.toString()`, just build the string representation yourself.

```
String prefix = "...proper divisors: ";
// Same number of chars as prefix, just all spaces.
String emptyPrefix = prefix.replaceAll(".", " ");
for (int i = 0; i < properDivisors.length;) {

  // Take as many of the items in the array as you can, without exceeding the
  // max line length.
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(prefix);
  for (; i < properDivisors.length; ++i) {
    int lengthBefore = sb.length();

    // Append the next item, and comma, if it would be needed.
    sb.append(properDivisors[i]);
    if (i + 1 < properDivisors.length) sb.append(",");

    if (sb.length() > maxWidth) {
      // Truncate back to the length before appending.
      sb.setLength(lengthBefore);
      break;
    }
  }
  System.out.println(sb);

  // Blank out the prefix, so you will print leading spaces on next line.
  prefix = emptyPrefix;
}
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/2tChFo)

Comment: Thank you! I've been working on this for hours. Makes a lot more sense now.

Comment: However, it seems that the last number on each line is getting cut off.

Comment: @Ayelir remove the `++i` from the outer for loop.